# VBA Data Search, select, copy and past in new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a database sheet that never changes, and I get every day multiple documents with lots of data... what I would like to have is a tool/code that searches in de new documents to data that is in my database sheet, and copy it to a new sheet.

I found a VBA code that searches for data, but I have to insert in a input box what I'm looking for.

```
    Sub FindText()
     Dim ws As Worksheet, Found As Range
     Dim myText As String, FirstAddress As String
     Dim AddressStr As String, foundNum As Integer

      myText = InputBox("Enter text to find")

     If myText = "" Then Exit Sub

      Sheets("Search").Select
      Range("A2:L625748").Select
      Selection.ClearContents
      Range("A1").Select

     For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
     With ws
      'Do not search Search sheet
     If ws.Name = "Gevonden" Then GoTo myNext

      Set Found = .UsedRange.Find(what:=myText, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)

      If Not Found Is Nothing Then
      FirstAddress = Found.Address

      Do
      foundNum = foundNum + 1
      AddressStr = AddressStr & .Name & " " & Found.Address & vbCrLf

      Set Found = .UsedRange.FindNext(Found)

      'Copy found data row to sheet4 Option!
       Found.EntireRow.Copy _
       Destination:=Worksheets("Search").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
       Loop While Not Found Is Nothing And Found.Address <> FirstAddress
      End If

        myNext:
      End With

        Next ws

       If Len(AddressStr) Then
       MsgBox "Found: """ & myText & """ " & foundNum & " times." & vbCr & _
       AddressStr, vbOKOnly, myText & " found in these cells"
       Else:

       MsgBox "Unable to find " & myText & " in this workbook.", vbExclamation
        End If
        End Sub
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. We can help you out if you have problems, but we will not implement this entire "tool/code" for you. Especially not with this little details.

Comment: sorry I forgot to ad what I already had. Now I can search, but only what I type in the input box, I would like it to compare both sheets and copy/paste the similar data.

Answer (score 0):

The direct way is to write VBA code. However as you have a lot of manual work to do, it may be better to keep it "manual".

To have a quick check on the new items, you can use the VLOOKUP function to the existence of records. Add a new column with the correct VLOOKUP, and then filter those which are not "#N/A". Next time when you need to overwrite the new data, just paste the data and it should do the job already.

Answer (score 0):

After some try's and lots of help from Google, i made something that works, but to achieve what i want i still need to delete some rows with "//" and the word "Local" in it.
Can any of you help me? This is what I have made so far:

```
Public Sub FindInput()
'Run from standard module, like: Module1.
'Find all data on all sheets!
'Do not search the sheet the found data is copied to!
'List a message box with all the found data addresses, as well!
  Dim ws As Worksheet, Found As Range
  Dim myText As String, FirstAddress As String
  Dim AddressStr As String, foundNum As Integer

  myText = (":I.")

  If myText = "" Then Exit Sub

  Sheets("Inputs").Select
  Range("A2:L625748").Select
  Selection.ClearContents
  Range("A1").Select

  For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
  With ws
  'Do not search Search sheet
   If ws.Name = "Inputs" Then GoTo myNext

   Set Found = .UsedRange.Find(What:=myText, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not Found Is Nothing Then
    FirstAddress = Found.Address

      Do
        foundNum = foundNum + 1
        AddressStr = AddressStr & .Name & " " & Found.Address & vbCrLf

     Set Found = .UsedRange.FindNext(Found)

    'Copy found data row to sheet4 Option!
     Found.EntireRow.Copy _
     Destination:=Worksheets("Inputs").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
     Loop While Not Found Is Nothing And Found.Address <> FirstAddress
     End If

     myNext:
     End With

     Next ws


      Cells.Replace What:="'", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
    xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

      Cells.Replace What:="NOT", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
    xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False


      Columns("A:A").Select
      Selection.Replace What:=":", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
         SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
          ReplaceFormat:=False

          Columns("A:A").Select
        Selection.Replace What:="(", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
       ReplaceFormat:=False

     Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Replace What:=".Data", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:="Data", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:="Ch", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:=".0", Replacement:=".00", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:=".1", Replacement:=".01", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:=".2", Replacement:=".02", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:=".3", Replacement:=".03", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:=".4", Replacement:=".04", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:=".5", Replacement:=".05", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:=".6", Replacement:=".06", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:=".7", Replacement:=".07", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:=".8", Replacement:=".08", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:=".9", Replacement:=".09", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:=".010", Replacement:=".10", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:=".011", Replacement:=".11", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:=".012", Replacement:=".12", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:=".013", Replacement:=".13", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:=".014", Replacement:=".14", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:=".015", Replacement:=".15", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:=".016", Replacement:=".16", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:=".017", Replacement:=".17", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:=".018", Replacement:=".18", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:=".019", Replacement:=".19", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:=".020", Replacement:=".20", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:=".021", Replacement:=".21", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:=".022", Replacement:=".22", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:=".023", Replacement:=".23", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:=".024", Replacement:=".24", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:=".025", Replacement:=".25", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:=".026", Replacement:=".26", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:=".027", Replacement:=".27", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:=".028", Replacement:=".28", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:=".029", Replacement:=".29", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:=".030", Replacement:=".30", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:=".031", Replacement:=".31", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Dim D As Range

    Columns("B:B").Select

    For Each D In Selection
     If Left(D.Value, 1) = " " Then
     D.Value = Right(D.Value, Len(D.Value) - 1)
    End If
    Next D

 End Sub
```